# render html from string without affecting formatting

Tags: jsf

The HTML content from an email is being included into an xhtml file

```
<h:outputText escape="false"
                value="#{emailBean.emailMessage.html}" />
```

JSF seems to strip the surrounding html tag and move namespaces and style etc to the top of the output.  This messes up the page style.

For example an email sent from Outlook, lots of namespaces are moved to html tag.

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></html>
```

The body gets link and vlink attributes which weren't there before.

```
<body lang="EN-GB" link="blue" vlink="purple"></body>
```

And there are loads of meta tags and style definitions.

Is there any way to embed the html so it styles properly but doesn't mess with the main page formatting?

Comment: What namespaces are covered by Email contents? Moving CSS styles on top of a page should not affect styling.

Comment: You could preprocess the email data with a custom converter prior to render it, so fixing conflicts or other unwanted behaviors.